# равнобедренный треугольник Python

Tags: python

нужно нарисовать равнобедренный треугольник при нечетных n. Не получается реализовать вложенный цикл на убывание рисования. Как сделать второй вложенный цикл, чтоб чертил звездочки на убывание?(Нужно использовать вложенные циклы)

```
n = 5
for i in range(1,n+1):
   if i <= n//2+1:
      for j in range(i):
         print('*',end='')
   elif i >n//2+1:
      for j in range(n//2,0,-1):
         print('*',end='')
   print()
```

Comment: Интик, гениально, спасибо за подсказку, я уже сломал голову за последние два часа))) СПАСИБО!

Comment: куда исчез комментарий от "Интик"?

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код вызывает в памяти поговорку "зачем делать просто, когда можно сделать сложно" :)

Такой вариант не устраивает?

```
n = 5
for i in range(n//2+1):
      print('*' * (i+1))
for i in range(n//2, 0, -1):
      print('*' * i)
```

Comment: в условии к задаче нужно использовать вложенный цикл, в вашем примере простые два цикла.

Comment: В условиях задачи, может, и нужно, а в вашем вопросе этого не сказано.

Comment: пардон, исправил, упустил этот момент в формулировке

Comment: Тогда можно заменить каждый print  на цикл. Такое удовлетворяет условиям?

Comment: добавил комментарий "Интик", я успел прочитать, использовать в третьем цикле не убывание, а просто уменьшение при возрастании  - for j in range(0,n-i+1). Этот вариант сработал, то что нужно, но коммент уже исчез куда-то. Зато решение получается хорошее)

Answer (score 2):

вот решение при нечетных n. Нужно использовать не убывание а уменьшение на возрастании в третьем цикле в зависимости от i. Подсказка от "Интик"

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
   if i <= n//2+1:
      for j in range(i):
         print('*',end='')
   elif i >n//2+1:
      for j in range(0,n-i+1):
         print('*',end='')
   print()
```

Также есть решение еще круче, с одним вложенным циклом:

```
n=5
for i in range(n):
    k = (n // 2 + 1) - abs(n // 2 - i)
    for _ in range(k):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
```

результат:

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1 (вложенный цикл):**

```
n = 7
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n // 2 - abs(n // 2 - i) + 1):
      print('*', end='')
    print()
```

**вариант 2 (почти вложенный цикл, т.е. внутри цикла есть цикл, но это не совсем вложенный):**

```
n = 7
for i in range(n):
    print(*['*' for j in range(n // 2 - abs(n // 2 - i) + 1)], sep='')
```

**вариант 2.1 (через формирование строки):**

```
n = 7
for i in range(n):
    print(''.join('*' for j in range(n // 2 - abs(n // 2 - i) + 1)), sep='')
```

**вариант 2.2 (циклы вложенные есть... технически):**

```
n = 7
print('\n'.join(''.join('*' for j in range(n // 2 - abs(n // 2 - i) + 1)) for i in range(n)))
```